# What specific exercises can be done in a swimming pool to aid recovery after a workout?

Tags: muscle-recovery, workout-types

I'm looking for some exercises that I can do in a swimming pool that will help my muscles to recover after a workout.

I've seen footballers on TV walking/jogging in the swimming pool the day after a match. If you can provide some specific exercises and also timings for when this should be done (e.g. immediately after the workout or next day etc.)

Could doing exercises in a pool actually provide more strain on the muscles if overdone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess one of the benefits of working out in a swimming pool offloads the joints vertically (you're floating after all), so after a heavy workout this reduces the strain on the fatigued muscles.

But it can still be a great workout, because it increases the resistance in pretty much any direction. So it's a great resistance training for the muscles that make your leg swing (back and forward), because they have to overcome a much larger resistance than during normal running. To get the same forces while running normally, you'd probably have to increase your speed to above your lactate threshold, which means your exercise wouldn't last very long.

So I guess you train in a swimming pool to train certain muscles without overusing your regular muscle groups, because of the non-weight bearing condition.

Answer (score 1):

Is this for after weights?

If so, swim for a few laps concentrating on your arms/shoulders.  [You will be swimming to work your muscles not your stroke.]  For example, swim freestyle but keep your hand open, fingers together, as you push through the water, giving a little resistance to work the muscles.  You can also do chest fly's standing in the pool and also bicep curls and tricep push downs, all with hands open.